# PHP Memcached on Ipage doesn't work

Tags: php, memcached

I have recently learnt how to use Memcache in PHP to query repeated rows from database more efficiently. But when I try to run the same script on server, it fails. I'm using Ipage as a web host. It is working fine on localhost.

Do I have to install memcache on Ipage or Ipage doesn't support PHP memcache?

Answer (score 0):

No $1.89/month shared host is going to offer memcached.

Comment: I'd be very surprised to see it on *any* shared web host. memcached isn't intended for a multitenant environment; there's no authentication or data isolation.